# Draw a Hanoi in C graphic with Code Block

Tags: c, bgi, towers-of-hanoi

Forgive my poor English.
I write a code to present Hanoi algorithm. And I want to show a simple animation.
like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2YSdRJg0s8
But I don't really know when should I call the drawing function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#define X1 150
#define X2 300
#define X3 450
#define witdh 10

void hanoi(int, char, char, char);
void printWin(int n);
void printBar(char ch,int n);
int mouse();

int time = 0;
int A=0,B=0,C=0;

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    printWin(3);
    mouse();



    system("pause");
}

void hanoi(int n, char A, char B, char C)
{
    int i;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        //I want to draw a animation instead this text describe.
        printf("%d: move %d from %c to %c\n", ++time, n, A, C); 

    }
    else
    {
        hanoi(n - 1, A, C, B);
        printBar('A',n);  //I dont know how to use printBar property
        delay(200);
        //I want to draw a animation instead this text describe.
        printf("%d: move %d from %c to %c\n", ++time, n, A, C);
        //So I use printBar.But its incorrect
        printBar('C',n);
        hanoi(n - 1, B, A, C);
        delay(200);
        printBar('B',n);
    }
}

void printWin(int n)  //initial the button and draw the window
{
    int Y1=250,Y2=200,Y3=300;
    initwindow(800, 600);
    char msg[10];
    int i=0;
    sprintf(msg,"%d",n);

    rectangle(X1-50,300,X1+50,350);  //button GO
    rectangle(X2-50,300,X2+50,350);  //button ADD
    rectangle(X3-50,300,X3+50,350);  //button SUB
    outtextxy(140,315,"GO");
    outtextxy(290,315,"ADD");
    outtextxy(440,315,"SUB");
    outtextxy(360,320,"       ");
    outtextxy(360,315,msg);

    rectangle(X1,Y1,X1+5,Y1-100);
    rectangle(X2,Y1,X2+5,Y1-100);
    rectangle(X3,Y1,X3+5,Y1-100);


    rectangle(X1-50,Y1,X1+50,Y1+5);
    rectangle(X2-50,Y1,X2+50,Y1+5);
    rectangle(X3-50,Y1,X3+50,Y1+5);

    outtextxy(X1,Y1+15,"A");
    outtextxy(X2,Y1+15,"B");
    outtextxy(X3,Y1+15,"C");

    for(i=n;i>0;i--) printBar('A',i);   //draw the initial statement(with 5 sticks
}
void printBar(char ch,int n)   //drawing bar in hanoi
{
    int x=0,y=0;
    int Y1=250,Y2=200,Y3=300;
    setfillstyle(SOLID_FILL,WHITE);
    if(ch=='A')
    {
        x=X1;
        A++;
        y=Y1-A*witdh;
    }
    if(ch=='B')
    {
        x=X2;
        B++;
        y=Y1-B*witdh;
    }
    if(ch=='C')
    {
        x=X3;
        C++;
        y=Y1-C*witdh;
    }
    //rectangle(X1,Y1,X1+5,Y1-100);

    bar(x-n*witdh,y,x+n*witdh,y-5);
}
int mouse()  //get the button click
{
    int x,y;
    while(!ismouseclick(WM_RBUTTONDOWN))
    {
        if(ismouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN))
        getmouseclick(WM_LBUTTONDOWN,x,y);
        //printf("%d%d",x,y);
        if(x>(X1-50)&&x<X1+50)
        {
            hanoi(3, 'A', 'B', 'C');
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the posted code logic seems very flawed as only a single mouse click will be handled then the program will hit the statement system("pause"); then exit

Comment: `#include <sstream>` ... hmmm ... are you sure you're using a C compiler?